# ¿Cómo mandar una formula matemática de un text input formateada a otro input?

Tags: javascript, html

Éste es mi codigo:

```js
function enviarTexto() {
  var texto = document.getElementById("inputText2").value;
  document.getElementById("inputText").value = texto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inputText" readonly="readonly">

<br>

<input type="text" id="inputText2">
<input type="button" id="botonText" onclick="enviarTexto()" value="Enviar">
```

Pongo una formula matemática en el campo junto al botón y al pulsar el botón quiero que me la muestre formateada, pero me la devuelve igual.

Por ejemplo, si pongo esta formula de latex `x_{1}+x_{2}=0`; al presionar "enviar", quiero que me la devuelva como formula matemática: x<sub>1</sub>+x<sub>2</sub>. Pero al presionar "enviar" me la devuelve igual así x_{1}+x_{2}=0.

No quiero que sume el resultado, si no que me la mande en formateada con MathJax. ¿Qué me falta? ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: No se entiende su pregunta? Usted lo que quiere mandar a el otro input es el resultado de la formula o que es lo que quiere hacer?

Comment: ya la e modificado, espero se entienda mejor

Comment: En base a que debería cambiar eso por lo otro ??? De donde saca usted que x_{1}+x_{2}=0 se debe traducir en xsub1 más xsub2??? No se si usted necesita algo similar a esto : https://jsbin.com/?html,output y si es así lo que le toca es leer y analizar la documentación de mathjax

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    function enviarTexto() {
       // conversion
       let conversion = {
       "{" : "",
       "}" : "",
       "_" : "",
       "0" : "⁰",
       "1" : "¹",
       "2" : "²",
       "3" : "³",
       "4" : "⁴",
       "5" : "⁵",
       "6" : "⁶",
       "7" : "⁷",
       "8" : "⁸",
       "9" : "⁹"
      };
      let regex = RegExp(`[${Object.keys(conversion).join("")}]`, "g");
      var texto = document.getElementById("inputText2").value;
      // utilizamos una expresion regular para remplazar por nada
      //texto = texto.replace(/[_{}]/gm, "" );
      // rep
      let formula = texto.replace(regex, num => conversion[num]);
      document.getElementById("inputText").value = formula;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputText" readonly="readonly">
<br>
<input type="text" id="inputText2" value="x_{1}+x_{2}=0">
<input type="button" id="botonText" onclick="enviarTexto()" value="Enviar">
```